# How do I verify that an ssh public/private keypair go together, is it different for openssl and ssh-key generated keys?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, pem, der, modulus

## Generating a Private Key...

```
$ openssl genrsa -out ./oci_api_key.pem 2048
```

## Generate a Public Key...from the private key:

I'm trying to generate a public key from a private key in [PEM format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) (the [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of a [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding)) by running:

```
$ openssl rsa -pubout -in ./oci_api_key.pem -out ./oci_api_key_public.pem
```

Next I'd like to:

## Verify they go together...by [comparing their MODULUS](https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art054#ssl_rsa)...

### Private Key Modulus:

```
$ openssl rsa -in ./oci_api_key.pem -noout -modulus
MODULUS=<long-hex-number>
```

### Public Key Modulus (doesn't work):

```
$ openssl x509 -in ./oci_api_key_public.pem -noout -modulus
```

So what am I missing here?
    unable to load certificate
    140084471075264:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

But it doesn't appear to work.  My public key doesn't have the `TRUSTED CERTIFICATE` line in it instead it's `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`

Comment: A certificate is not a public key and a public key is not a certificate. A (X.509 PK-not-Attr) certificate _contains_ a public key but that is quite different from _being_ a public key.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that guy’s site must have an error in it; but he wrote a whole book on how to implement the algorithm, so I just assumed he knew what he was talking about l.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-pubin` to your openssl rsa invocation to work with the public key:

```
$ openssl rsa -pubin -in ./oci_api_key_public.pem -noout -modulus
```

Comment: Note OpenSSH since 7.8 (2018-08) by default writes OpenSSH's own 'new format' files which cannot be processed by OpenSSL. We have _many_ Qs on this, some on other Stacks; google +ssh-keygen +"-m pem"